# Internet needs dhclient command to connect

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp

I'm running a headless server on ODROID-C1 with Ubuntu 18.04. I connected to Wifi with wpa_supplicant and `iwconfig` shows the correct SSID association, but on startup it does not work - `ping google.com` returns `Temporary failure in name resolution`, and `ping 192.168.1.1` (the router IP) returns `connect: Network is unreachable`.

To get the internet to work, I have to run `dhclient -4` to fix it, and after a while it breaks again?

This happens with Ethernet and Wifi connections.

What is going wrong? What should I do to fix it permanently? (I don't want to have to run this command blind every time it is started)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would [this](https://gist.github.com/mohamadaliakbari/1cb9400984094541581fff07143e1c9d) solve your issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 uses netplan to configure networking. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @BrianZ It might work in the short term, but as I said the internet breaks eventually after running the command so I'm not sure if it'll work.

Comment: @chili555 `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` returns `No such file or directory`, it doesn't exist for some reason

Comment: How about: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `sudo dpkg -s netplan.io | grep Status`